# ,">"&0),"") at the end of a countif formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the below formula, but don't understand why the last part of it ,">"&0),""). Can somebody clarify pls?

```
=IF(COUNTIF($AJ$2:$AJ9,$AJ9)=1,COUNTIFS($AJ$2:$AJ11323,$AJ9,$AQ$2:$AQ11323,">"&0),"")
```

Comment: read documentation and look at examples: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx

Comment: `">"&0` can also be written as `">0"` which may be more transparent

Answer (score 3):

> =IF(COUNTIF($AJ$2:$AJ9,$AJ9)=1,COUNTIFS($AJ$2:$AJ11323,$AJ9,$AQ$2:$AQ11323,">"&0),"")

- We can break this up - `IF(Logical Test, True condition, False condition)` - the `false condition` is your last `""`

  - [if function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/quick-reference-card-RZ102425926.aspx?CTT=1&section=6&mode=print)

---

- Your `Logical test` is `countif() = 1` and your `true condition` is `countifs > 0`

  - [countif function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/countif-function-HA102753077.aspx?CTT=1)

---

- Your `true condition` is `countifs(first range, first criteria, second range, second criteria)`

  - [countifs function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/countif-function-HA102753077.aspx?CTT=1)

---

- This means `AJ2:AJ11323 = AJ9` is `criteria 1` and `AQ2:AQ11323 >0` is `criteria 2`

The end of your formula is the second criteria of countifs and the false condition of your if.

Answer (score 2):

From the [MS Office help on the `COUNTIFS` function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx):

```
COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2]…)
```

The `COUNTIFS` function syntax has the following arguments:

- `criteria_range1`    Required. The first range in which to evaluate the associated criteria.
- `criteria1`    Required. The criteria in the form of a number, expression, cell reference, or text that define which cells will be counted. For example, criteria can be expressed as `32`, `">32"`, `B4`, `"apples"`, or `"32"`.
- `criteria_range2`, `criteria2`, ...    Optional. Additional ranges and their associated criteria. Up to 127 range/criteria pairs are allowed.

Let's consider your case (only the last `COUNTIFS`, of course):

```
COUNTIFS($AJ$2:$AJ11317,$AJ3,$AQ$2:$AQ11317,">"&0)
```

The first `criteria_range`, `criteria1` pair is `$AJ$2:$AJ11317`, `$AJ3` while the second `criteria_range2`, `criteria2` pair is `$AQ$2:$AQ11317`, `">"&0`. `criteria2` (or `">"&0`) evaluates to `">0"` (`">"&0` is equivalent to `">0"`) which is true if any of the values in `$AQ$2:$AQ11317` is greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
=IF(Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

So the empty string `""` at the end is just the value to take if `COUNTIF(...) <> 1`.

The other part you don't understand is an argument to `COUNTIFS`, which is much like `COUNTIF` but with multiple ranges and conditions. Basically, it counts all the rows `2 <= n <= 11323` where `AJn = AJ9` *and* `AQn = ">"&0`.